stator current in induction motor when load increases
When the load increases the speed of the rotor decreases and so the relative speed of the rotor and the magnetic field of the stator increase (slip increase). As a result, the induced emf will increase, increasing the rotor current and finally increasing the torque to support the load connected.
But why will the stator current increase? I read that it increases because the needed output power is increased but is there a more detailed explanation of the process this increase occurs? Also, I thought that when the speed of the rotor initially decreased, the back emf induced in the stator windings to limit the current would decrease. As a result, the current increases, and the magnetic field of the stator gets stronger increasing the induced emf in the rotor windings. Then the current in the rotor increases and the torque increases to the value of the load torque. Is it correct?
